# Cant modify source code (c++) of included code, file not found

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, encoding, mingw

I am using mingw to compile.
I am trying to improve the library https://github.com/ftylitak/qzxing
to support reading different encoded segments.

But if i write a space at the end of a line, i save the file, i remove the space, and save it again, it will not compile telling it cant include a header because file not found.

I think it is about file encoding, but i cant find out how to solve it.

I am using Qt5.9

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Notepad++ will let you change the encoding and line endings on a file. I would try that. https://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: i tried encoding before, without luck.
Now i tried to change end line encoding... no luck but something more
If i open a file with notepad++, i change end line encoding, save, change back to the linux one, same error happends...

Comment: This isn't going to be helpful, still I want to make this note. At all cost, avoid developing on Windows,  if you can afford that, especially with hybrid tools like `mingw`. Better set up a Linux virtual machine with a proper environment. UNIX / Linux was built by developers, for developers, unlike MS Windows.

Comment: Regarding your problem, the specific error is necessary to be able to help you, and the file itself probably is necessary as well.

Comment: Just touching any file in that library, under windows, problem happends
It fails to find file for the include #include <QtCore> at QZXing_global.h, that is, first include in the library.

I need to target windows/linux/android, that use to be easy with Qt under windows using mingw.